# how can i reduce the margin left and top in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

i need help with my code
using bootstrap to design n new in it. did the top nav, doing the side bar. but the left bar not lapping to the left completelty and the gap between the top and the side is too much. how can i reduce it

```
<!--BEGINING NAV=========================-->

            <nav  class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../img/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">General Requirment</a></li>


      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control inputcurve" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default redbut"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search red"></button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span> 07063859559</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span> info@myactiveschool.com</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Chike Okoli Vitalis <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu nav1">
             <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i> Profile Picture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Account Setting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

 <!--END NAV=========================-->

               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                       <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked span3">
                           <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>Home</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>About us</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
               </div>       

<!--START SIDE NAV===================================================================================================================================-->
here is my css

 .side-nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 51px;
        left: 225px;
        width: 225px;
        margin-left: -225px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background-color: #222;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .side-nav>li>a {
        width: 225px;
    }

    .side-nav li a:hover,
    .side-nav li a:focus {
        outline: none;
        background-color: #000 !important;
    }
}

.side-nav>li>ul {
    padding: 0;
}

.side-nav>li>ul>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 38px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}

.side-nav>li>ul>li>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.side-nav{right: 0;left: auto;}
```

Comment: You add a class to the elements you want fixing like so, marginFix {margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px;} And as long as it is after the rest of the CSS it will overright the old css changing the margins

Comment: i did this way marginFix {margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px;} i know inserted it into                                                                                      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
     <div class="col-md-3">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked marginFix">          <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>About us</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
      </div>

Comment: it dint work maybe i dint add it well

Comment: Add the css at the bottom of your html page inside <style></style> tags. This way you know that it is the very last change and should garuntee a result